# How to make several DropDownlists read from the same datasource in a non-Redundant way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, formview

I have about 4 fields built inside a form view but each have to appear to a maximum of 10 if the user wishes to add more info (Note: this is required)

so its like :NameTextBox1 till NameTextBox10 and TestTextBox1 till TestTexBox10

If the user clicks the "add field" button the extra textboxes appear.

**Now for the Question:** One of the fields is a dropdownlist henceforth I have 10 dropdownlists that all have the same info they all read from the same function. Is there a more efficient way to go about doing the below procedure than writing the same thing 10 times?

```
 DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)EntryFormView.FindControl("DropDownList1");
  DropDownList1.DataSource = GeographicManager.ReadLocations();
  DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it into another function that takes IDs:

```
private void initDropDown(string dropDownID)
{
    DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)EntryFormView.FindControl(dropDownID);
    DropDownList1.DataSource = GeographicManager.ReadLocations();
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}

initDropDown("DropDownList1");
initDropDown("DropDownList2");
```

If you need to init them all at once, you can use a loop to do so:

```
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    initDropDown("DropDownList" + i);
}
```

Or you can put their IDs in an array and iterate over that. Also useful if your IDs do not follow simple pattern of "DropDownListX":

```
string[] dropDownIDs = ["DropDownList1", "DropDownListTwo", "TheDropDownList"];

foreach (String ID in dropDownIDs)
{
    initDropDown(ID);
}
```

Comment: Genius !! I apologize for such a question.

Comment: how would I capture the selected items in the multiple dropdownlists ? Because on select I need to load other readonly fields based on the item selected. But also they have the same functionality so I'd want to avoid redundancy

Comment: @helpwanted161, that's a different story, not fit for comments format. i suggest you open a new question for that

Comment: Noted. This is the link if you have an answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392234/how-to-capture-the-selected-values-in-multiple-dropdownlists-and-load-automatic)